# TypeError: must be str, not int couldn't be solved

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

The original time data is like this：

```
df['time'][0:4]

   2015-07-08
        05-11
        05-12
   2008-07-26
```

I want all these data contains year value.
And I applied this:

con_time = []

```
i=0
for i in df['time']:
    if len(df['time'])==5:
        time = '2018'+'-'+df['time']
        con_time.append(time)
        i +=1
    else:
        con_time.append(df['time']) 
        i +=1
```

Error occurred:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-b7d87c72f412> in <module>()
      8     else:
      9         con_time.append(df['time'])
---> 10         i +=1

TypeError: must be str, not int
```

This error is so strange....
Actually I want to create a new list, converting it to a np.array and concat it into the df.
Do I have a better way to achieve the goal?

Comment: use `con_time.append(str(df['time']))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have asked about an alternative approach. instead of an explicit loop in python and filling a list, one should rather use DataFrame methods directly. In your case this would be

```
df['time'].apply(lambda x: x if len(x) != 5 else '2018-'+x)
```

This might run faster for some datasets

**EDIT**
I actually ran a timing benchmark using a random toy dataset with ~50% of complete and incomplete dates. In short, it seems that for a small dataset the simple for-loop solution is faster for a large dataset both methods show similar performance:

```
# 1M examples
import random
import numpy as np
y = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,2,1000000))
s = {0:'2015-07-08',  1:'05-11'}
y = y.map(s)
%%timeit -n100
_ = y.apply(lambda x: x if len(x) != 5 else '2018-'+x)
>>> 275 ms ± 6.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%%timeit -n100
con_time = []
for i in y:
    if len(i)==5:
        time = '2018-'+i
        con_time.append(time)
    else:
        con_time.append(i) 
con_time_a = np.array(con_time)
>>> 289 ms ± 5.23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# 1K examples
import random
import numpy as np
y = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,2,1000))
s = {0:'2015-07-08',  1:'05-11'}
y = y.map(s)
%%timeit -n100
_ = y.apply(lambda x: x if len(x) != 5 else '2018-'+x)
>>> 431 µs ± 70.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%%timeit -n100
con_time = []
for i in y:
    if len(i)==5:
        time = '2018-'+i
        con_time.append(time)
    else:
        con_time.append(i) 
con_time_a = np.array(con_time)
>>> 289 µs ± 40.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

you have two `i` variables, when you make `i += 1` you take `i` variable from

```
for i in df['time']
```

not

```
i = 0
```

change `i` variable from for loop with another name , for example if you don't need variable from for loop statment you can name it `_` (underscore)

Comment: Actually, this alone will not solve the problem, because inside the loop one should use the iterator, e.g. `i`, **not** appending `df['time']` directly

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi of course this not solve all problems, because he concatenate `'2018'+'-'+df['time']` where `df['time']` is a list, and it will raise a `type Error: must be str, not list`, he need to use your code , but i don't think he will understand it